# Replace characters in polygon data

Tags: postgresql

I have a polygon column in my table and currently it shows data like this:

```
((114.22043434297007,22.278209),(114.22020060314003,22.282611726493),(114.21950163468,22.286972052322),(114.21834416903994,22.291247985168), etc...
```

I want to change it to display like this:

```
((lon1 lat1, lon2 lat2, lon... lat..., lonN latN))
```

Is this possible in Postgres?

Comment: How do you display these values? Postgres itself is just database

Comment: Looks like `asewkt()` and stripping of the `POLYGON()` wrapper does the job. But why do that in the database?